# trying to fix this but cant find a solution

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, cython

Hey I am new to coding and I wanted to fix this can somebody help me here is my code and error by the way this is a discord bot that I am trying to make it work but seems to be running into this issue constantly is there any other way I can replace the masters and run it some other way

```
#cython: language_level=3

import data
import config
import discord
import userCommands
import adminCommands

from discordHelper import newEmbed, errorMessage, RED, BLUE, GREEN, YELLOW

PREFIX = '+'


class DiscordBot(discord.Client):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        allData = data.loadJSON(data.DATABASE_FILENAME)
        self.masterIDs = allData['Masters']
        self.staffIDs = allData['Staff']

    async def on_ready(self):
        '''
            Called when the discord bot logs in
        '''
        print(f'{self.user.name} Logged In!')
        print('--------------------\n')

    async def on_reaction_add(self, reaction: discord.Reaction, user: discord.User):
        # Unsubscribe from vouch notifications
        description = reaction.message.embeds[0].description
        if 'Received a' in description and reaction.emoji == '❌':
            noNotifs = data.loadJSON(data.DATABASE_FILENAME)[
                'NoNotificationIDs']
            if user.id not in noNotifs:
                embed = newEmbed(
                    description='Unsubscribed from notifications!')
                embed.set_footer(
                    text='To resubscribe, react with ✅')
                noNotifs.append(user.id)
                data.updateJson(data.DATABASE_FILENAME, {
                                'NoNotificationIDs': noNotifs})
                await user.send(embed=embed)

        # Resubscribe to vouch notifications
        elif 'Unsubscribed' in description and reaction.emoji == '✅':
            noNotifs = data.loadJSON(data.DATABASE_FILENAME)[
                'NoNotificationIDs']
            if user.id in noNotifs:
                embed = newEmbed(description='Resubscribed to notifications!')
                embed.set_footer(text='To unsubscribe, react with ❌')
                noNotifs.remove(user.id)
                data.updateJson(data.DATABASE_FILENAME, {
                                'NoNotificationIDs': noNotifs})
                await user.send(embed=embed)

    async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
        '''
            Handles all the discord commands
        '''
        # Make sure we don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        isMaster = message.author.id in self.masterIDs
        isStaff = message.author.id in self.staffIDs or isMaster
        loweredMsg = message.content.lower()
        words = message.content.split()

        # =====================================================

        if loweredMsg.startswith('+vouch') or loweredMsg.startswith('-vouch'):
            if len(message.mentions) == 0 or len(words) < 3:
                await errorMessage('Please follow this format: [+ or -]vouch [@user] [message]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            if message.author.id == message.mentions[0].id:
                await errorMessage('You cannot vouch for yourself.', message.channel)
                return

            vouchMessage = ' '.join(words[2:])
            isPositive = loweredMsg[0] == '+'
            pendingChannel = self.get_channel(config.PENDING_VOUCHES_CHANNELID)
            await userCommands.vouch(message.author,
                                     message.mentions[0],
                                     vouchMessage,
                                     isPositive,
                                     message.channel,
                                     pendingChannel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}dwc') and isMaster:
            if 'dwc1' in loweredMsg:
                level = 1
            elif 'dwc2' in loweredMsg:
                level = 2
            elif 'dwc3' in loweredMsg:
                level = 3
            else:
                level = 0

            if len(message.mentions) == 0 or (level != 0 and len(words) < 3):
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}dwc [@user] [reason]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            reason = ' '.join(words[2:]) if level != 0 else ''
            await adminCommands.dwc(message.mentions[0], level, reason, message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}scammer') and isMaster:
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}scammer [@user]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            await adminCommands.scammer(message.mentions[0], message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}pending') and isStaff:
            await adminCommands.pending(message.channel, self.get_user)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}leaderboard'):
            await userCommands.leaderboard(message.channel, self.get_user, self.user.avatar_url)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}reply') and isStaff:
            if len(words) < 3 or not words[1].isdigit():
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}reply [vouch id] [message]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            targetUser = None
            try:
                vouchID = int(words[1])
                pending = data.loadJSON(data.DATABASE_FILENAME)['PendingVouches']
                for i in pending:
                    if i['ID'] == vouchID:
                        targetUser = self.get_user(i['Giver'])
                        break
                else:
                    raise Exception('User not found')

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                await errorMessage(f'Could not find user with ID {vouchID}',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            replyMsg = ' '.join(words[2:])
            await adminCommands.reply(targetUser, replyMsg, message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}remove') and isMaster:
            if len(message.mentions) == 0 or len(words) < 2:
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format:\n{PREFIX}remove [@user]\n**or**\n{PREFIX}remove [@user] [vouch ID]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            vouchNum = -1
            if len(words) >= 3 and words[2].isdigit():
                vouchNum = int(words[2])
                if vouchNum < 0:
                    await errorMessage('Vouch ID cannot be negative!', message.channel)
                    return

            await adminCommands.remove(message.mentions[0], message.channel, vouchNum)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}verify') and isMaster:
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}verify [@user]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            await adminCommands.verify(message.mentions[0], message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif (loweredMsg.startswith('+add') or loweredMsg.startswith('-add')) and isMaster:
            if len(message.mentions) == 0 or len(words) < 3:
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: [+ or -]add [@user] [giverID (optional)] [message]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            # Check if they specify the giver ID
            hasGiverID = False
            giverID = 0
            if words[2].isdigit():
                hasGiverID = True
                giverID = int(words[2])

            vouchMessage = ' '.join(
                words[3:]) if hasGiverID else ' '.join(words[2:])
            isPositive = loweredMsg[0] == '+'
            logChannel = self.get_channel(config.LOG_CHANNEL_ID)
            await adminCommands.add(message.author,
                                    message.mentions[0],
                                    vouchMessage,
                                    isPositive,
                                    message.channel,
                                    logChannel,
                                    giverID)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}token'):
            await userCommands.token(message.author, message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}profile'):
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                user = message.author
            else:
                user = message.mentions[0]

            await userCommands.profile(
                targetUser=user,
                bcGuild=self.get_guild(583416004974084107),
                channel=message.channel
            )

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}link'):
            if len(words) < 2:
                await errorMessage(
                    f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}link [https://nulled.to/ link]',
                    message.channel)
                return

            if 'https://nulled.to/' not in words[1]:
                await errorMessage(
                    'Please provide a proper nulled.to link!',
                    message.channel)
                return

            await userCommands.link(message.author, words[1], message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}redeem'):
            if len(words) <= 1:
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}redeem [token]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            await userCommands.redeem(message.author, words[1],
                                      message.channel, self.logChannel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}admin') and isMaster:
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}admin [@user]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            await adminCommands.admin(message.mentions[0], message.channel)
            if message.mentions[0].id in self.masterIDs:
                self.masterIDs.remove(message.mentions[0].id)
            else:
                self.masterIDs.append(message.mentions[0].id)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}staff') and isMaster:
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}staff [@user]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            await adminCommands.staff(message.mentions[0], message.channel)
            if message.mentions[0].id in self.staffIDs:
                self.staffIDs.remove(message.mentions[0].id)
            else:
                self.staffIDs.append(message.mentions[0].id)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}blacklist') and isMaster:
            if len(message.mentions) == 0:
                if len(words) >= 2 and not words[1].isdigit():
                    await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}blacklist [@user]',
                                       message.channel)
                    return

            if len(message.mentions) != 0:
                id = message.mentions[0].id
            else:
                id = int(words[1])

            await adminCommands.blacklist(id, message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif (loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}approve') or
              loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}accept')) and isStaff:
            if len(words) < 2 or not words[1].isdigit():
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}approve [vouch ID]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            ids = [int(i) for i in words[1:] if i.isdigit()]
            logChannel = self.get_channel(config.LOG_CHANNEL_ID)
            for i in ids:
                await adminCommands.approve(i, message.channel,
                                            logChannel, self.get_user)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}deny') and isStaff:
            if len(words) < 2 or not words[1].isdigit():
                await errorMessage(f'Please follow this format: {PREFIX}deny [vouch ID]',
                                   message.channel)
                return

            ids = [int(i) for i in words[1:] if i.isdigit()]
            for i in ids:
                await adminCommands.deny(i, message.channel)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}help'):
            await userCommands.help(PREFIX,
                                    message.channel,
                                    isMaster)

        # =====================================================

        elif loweredMsg.startswith(f'{PREFIX}about'):
            await userCommands.about(message.channel, self.user.avatar_url)

        # =====================================================


def main():
    DiscordBot().run(config.DISCORD_TOKEN)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

(config.py

```
DISCORD_TOKEN = 'OwOD'
PENDING_VOUCHES_CHANNELID = 105159912
LOG_CHANNEL_ID = 1051599
```

here is the error

```
File "c:\Users\ne\Desktop\test bot\main.py", line 348, in main
    DiscordBot().run(config.DISCORD_TOKEN)
  File "c:\Users\ne\Desktop\test bot\main.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.masterIDs = allData['Masters']
KeyError: 'Masters'
```

I was expecting to work after changing some values but no solution

Comment: Have you checked that the JSON file in `data.DATABASE_FILENAME` corresponds to a dict that has `'Masters'` as key? That's what the error message is saying.

Comment: If you're new to coding I strongly recommend that you don't go anywhere near *discord* or any attempts at asynchronous processing until you've learned the basics. In particular (for this issue) you need to understand how Python dictionaries work

Comment: Please read about [mre]. What you've provided isn't minimal